# wordpress blank page for permalink redirect on apache2 server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, apache2.4

I try to migrate my wordpress from old server to new aws server.
I can visit the homepage, but the permalink page like:

```
https://ec2-34-218-47-207.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/homepage/
```

which is blank and nothing in there.

I use admin:admin as user and group.

the apache2.conf is:

```
# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
#Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
User admin
Group admin
```

I change user and group for it is convinent to use sftp to upload and download the files

The directory is:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 admin admin        4096 Aug 14 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 admin admin        4096 Jul 30 13:46 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin    32673740 Jul 31 00:37 backup
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin    33244158 Aug  1 07:40 backup200
-rw-rw-r--  1 admin www-data     2291 Aug  2 00:24 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin         470 Aug  1 14:15 .htaccess.save
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin         418 Sep 25  2013 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin     9503425 Jul  5 16:08 latest.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin       19935 Jan  6  2018 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin         181 Jul 25 01:41 phpinfo.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        7415 Aug 14 10:08 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        5458 May  1 22:10 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 admin admin        4096 Jul 31 05:07 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin         364 Dec 19  2015 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        1889 May  2 22:11 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        3111 Aug  2 00:24 wp-config.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        2853 Dec 16  2015 wp-config-sample.php
drwxr-xr-x 14 admin admin        4096 Aug 14 10:08 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        3669 Aug 20  2017 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 18 admin admin       12288 Jul 31 05:09 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        2422 Nov 21  2016 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        3306 Aug 22  2017 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin       37794 Aug 14 10:08 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        8048 Jan 11  2017 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin       16246 Oct  4  2017 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin       30091 Apr 29 23:10 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        4620 Oct 23  2017 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 admin admin        3065 Aug 31  2016 xmlrpc.php
```

I have already use command line:

```
 a2enmod rewrite
```

to enable rewrite page.

The .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

where is my configuration error?

I try to change the apache2.conf fellow the 
Samir Sheikh answer, but I get the errror fellow:

```
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Aug 14 11:46:48 ip-172-30-0-181 apachectl[16169]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 176 of /etc/apache2/
Aug 14 11:46:48 ip-172-30-0-181 apachectl[16169]: order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allo
Aug 14 11:46:48 ip-172-30-0-181 apachectl[16169]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 14 11:46:48 ip-172-30-0-181 apachectl[16169]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 14 11:46:48 ip-172-30-0-181 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited sta
Aug 14 11:46:48 ip-172-30-0-181 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: CAn you see admin panel?

Comment: Yes, I can see it

Comment: Can you try to update permalinks from admin panel

Comment: try placing index.html with some test code in root of wordpress and try loading the page again, its throwing 500 error, try enabling php error log

Comment: I can update permalinks from admin panel, but event if I do this there is still blank page.

Answer (score 0):

For those using apache. You will need to

- Ensure you have .htaccess in root path of the site you are hosting. Example /var/www
- Update the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

**From**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

**To**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

Second way

Please referred following links

http://linuxtric.blogspot.com/2013/05/wordpress-blank-page-occuring-when.html

https://www.supportsages.com/wp-blank-permalink-page-on-admin-interface/

Comment: I chane the question, I can not change just  Order allow, deny

Comment: Have you changed AllowOverride  none to ALL OR  have you increase WP_MEMORY_LIMIT in config ?

Comment: I change the allow Override but not increase WP_MEMORY_LIMIT in config

Comment: Please increase memory limit if still not done then try to delete .htaccess  file and re-create it using the default that Wordpress provided after  changed the permalink structure.

Comment: I increase memory limit in wpconfig.php by define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
I delete .htaccess and use the wordpress sample .htaccess but still not working.

Comment: Have you restart Apache server after changes in file AllowOverride All ?

Comment: Yes, of course restart, since there is error if I do not restart, there is an error on log

Comment: Let's connect in chat for discussion

Comment: How to connect in chat? what tools?

Comment: It'll move automatically once comments size will increase.

Comment: I got "Moving discussion to chat failed"

Comment: Same here , I am not able to move in chat.

Comment: http://www.lmhproductions.com/248/wordpress-permalink-page-isblank/
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

check too the file wp-config.php and try found some configuration wrong!

Check too if the the lines are right

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress');

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/wordpressp');

and other lines...